# Process jobs with Sidekiq Scheduler

Tags: sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-3

I'm not sure what I'm missing with my Sidekiq Scheduler setup. I can process jobs manually, but the scheduled jobs aren't running. Pressing `Enqueue Now` from the Web ui runs the job correctly. Starting sidekiq with `bundle exec sidekiq` says Schedules Loaded

Gemfile

```
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 6.5.4'
gem 'sidekiq-scheduler', '~> 5.0.3'
```

`config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`

```
if Rails.env.test?
  require 'sidekiq/testing'

  Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
else
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.average_scheduled_poll_interval = 5
    config.on(:startup) do
      SidekiqScheduleManager::StartupManager.call
      Sidekiq.schedule = Sidekiq.get_all_schedules
    end
  end
  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.average_scheduled_poll_interval = 5
  end
end
```

Creating a schedule with

```
def schedule_this(day)
  # Convert seconds since midnight to a time string,
  # The current time doesn't matter, we just need the time at the beginning of the day
  time = (Time.current.beginning_of_day + daily_schedule[day].seconds).strftime('%H:%M')
  # Schedule the job
  Sidekiq.set_schedule(
    "notify_#{member.id}_#{day}",
    schedule_arg(day, time, member)
  )
end

def schedule_arg(day, time, member)
  {
    # 'every' => ['1w', { 'first_at' => "#{day.capitalize} #{time}" }],
    # 'every' => "#{day} at #{time}",
    # 'every' => ['1w', { 'first_in' => "#{day} at #{time}" }],
    'cron' => Fugit::Nat.parse("every #{day} at #{time}").original,
    'class' => 'WaveJob',
    'args' => schedule_args_args(member)
  }
end
```

`set_schedule` produces records like this

`{"notify_649754255af1d03b3aecba50_monday"=>{"cron"=>"0 9 * * 1", "class"=>"WaveJob", "args"=>"[some_json]"},`

Update - Adding `Sidekiq::Scheduler.reload_schedule!` to the `:startup` block gets the jobs to process now, but editing a record's cron string isn't updating the schedules again. Re-running `reload_schedule!` from the console says SidekiqScheduler is disabled.

Update - Fixed it. Just needed `Sidekiq::Scheduler.dynamic = true` in the `:startup` block as well